# Bigger font for Android apps converted to the Blackberry Playbook?

Tags: blackberry-playbook

I converted my Android app to the Blackberry Playbook, but the screen density it's too small, everything is almost unreadable.
There is a way to force an higher dpi setting?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried chaning [applicationDPI](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c682e5a9412cf5976c17-8000.html)?

Comment: No luck, this settings are ignored while converting the apk